# Why use XOR or OR operator for "bypass" a conditional jump

Tags: reverse-engineering

I'm currently working on a challenge on root me but had to read the solution on internet because I couldn't progress anymore. I read [this article](http://m0x39.blogspot.fr/2013/01/reverse-engineering-password-protected.html) which talk about the challenge I'm currently working on.

He's "bypassing" (don't know if that is the right term) the JNS instruction using:

```
(gdb) set $eflags = $eflags ^ 128
```

And also the JNE using:

```
(gdb) set $eflags = $eflags | 64
```

Can anyone explain why he is using the XOR or the OR operator?
And why with the 128 value and the 64 value?

EDIT: This is a question I already asked on StackOverflow but nobody answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We are now at the JNS instruction. This means Jump Short if Not zero
>   ...
>   So lets go back to where the JNS instruction was and unset the SF flag
>   so the jump gets executed. SF is the 7th bit in the register so in
>   order to cancel it we need to xor with 2^7 = 128

There's actually an error in the first sentence here, `JNS` [means](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html) "Jump if Not Sign", i.e. jump is taken if sign flag is *not* set. The following logic is valid: he decides that he wants the jump to be taken since otherwise the program will exit. So the sign bit should be *cleared*.

As he says, the [sign flag is bit 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register), a `xor` with 128 (= 2^7, or `0b10000000` in binary) will flip it. (the result of a `xor` is `1` if exactly one of the input bits is `1`.) Since he checked just before that the bit was set, there's no risk of accidentally *setting* the bit. Generally one would `and` with the inverse (i.e. 127, or `0b01111111`) to clear the bit. (result of `and` is `1` if exactly both inputs are `1`.)
Wikipedia among others has [truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate#Symbols) for the logic functions.

In the second case, the bit at position 6 needs to be set, and `or` with 64 (= 2^6, or 01000000) does it. (result of `or` is `1` if *at least* one input bit is a `1`.) He could have used `xor` to toggle it too, but that would again require checking if the bit is set first.

Comment: So you mean that XOR is for set a flag and OR for unset ?

Comment: As the answer says The XOR with 10000000 will flip the 8th bit (0 goes to 1 and 1 goes to 0) and OR with 01000000 will always set the 7th bit to 1.

Comment: @S7_0 you need to read up on binary operations